# Update jQuery UI Tabs when the contents of one tab is updated

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, jquery-tabs

I have a jQuery UI Tab with 2 tabs. When I update my first tab and then click on the second tab, I want it to show updated informations, that the first tab updated. There is a `dropDownlist` on the first tab.

Comment: Do you have some code to show? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch the change event of tabs and for this see [this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Events) jquery tab documentation and on change of tab you have to get new record from your source